# Questions about 32 bit float values

Tags: floating-point, integer

Can all 16-bit unsigned integer (unsigned short) values be stored EXACTLY in a 32-bit floating point value?
Can all 32-bit unsigned integer (unsigned int) values be stored EXACTLY in a 32-bit floating point value?
Which of the numbers below can be represented EXACTLY with a 32-bit float value?
1.648, 2.75, 2.125, 10.999, 9.351, 0.625

Comment: Wasn't that covered in class?

Answer (score 1):

- All integers between -2<sup>24</sup> and 2<sup>24</sup> can be represented as single-precision floats.
- Neither -2<sup>24</sup>-1 nor 2<sup>24</sup>+1 can be represented as floats.

As a consequence all unsigned 16-bit integers can be represented exactly as floats, but not all unsigned 32-bit integers.

The explanation is that some bit patterns are used to represent fractional numbers such as 0.125 and 1.5, so fewer than 2<sup>32</sup> bit patterns are available for integers.

A simple program in your programming language of choice can tell you which of 1.648, 2.75, 2.125, 10.999, 9.351, 0.625 are exactly representable in single-precision: print, to 26 significant decimal digits (say, with the format `%.25e` using a `printf`-like function), the values of `1.648f`, …

When you type the floating-point constant `1.648f` in a program in most programming languages, it is translated to the single-precision float closest to 1648/1000. If this number prints as `1.64800000`, it means that the number 1.648 is exactly representable as a float. If it prints as something else, then 1.648 isn't representable (and the output tell you how far the nearest float happens to be).

Comment: So does that mean for the 3rd question that only 2.125 can be represented exactly with a 32 bit float value?

Comment: @JamesGrabowski I am surprised that you found that. What does your programming language display when you print the respective values of the other numbers with enough significant digits? Don't forget the `f` suffix or the equivalent notation in your programming language to indicate a single-precision floating-point number!

Comment: When I create floats of all those values and print them out, they all seems to work.

Comment: @JamesGrabowski I was confused. You need to print to **more** than 9 decimal digits to see either only trailing zeroes or non-zero digits. You are right, 0.625, 2.125 and 2.75 are the answers. A fractional number representable in binary floating-point always end with a 5, but the converse is not true (e.g. 0.05 is not representable in binary floating-point). http://ideone.com/IDWquE

Comment: The basic test is whether the number can be represented as a fraction whose denominator is a power of two. For example, 2.75 is 11/4, and 4 is a power of two. A number that fails that test cannot be exactly represented as a float. Numbers that pass but need too big a numerator or denominator also cannot be represented.